# How to batch upsert(insert or update) statements in dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a use case which need to batch insert or update dynamodb requests, and I could not find way to solve it. Any suggestions are welcome, thank you.

**My use case**

- Use case #1: For user entity, we will send Add/Update/Delete requests
- Use case #2: For Credit entity, we will only send Update request no matter there is record existed or not.

And Use case #1 and #2 are mixed, we need to batch them all together.

I tried couple of ways like below:

**Using batchWrite**

The issue is we can only batch `PutRequest` and `DeleteRequest`. It fits well for `Use case #2`, because if there is no record there, `PutRequest` will create one. If there is, `PutRequest` will replace it totally. But it didn't fit `Use case #1` well, because for `Update User` request, it will left the database only the modified columns. e.g, if I only update name column, `PutRequest` will replace totally and only name column will be left. Yes, we can provide all the columns when we update, but it is not ideal.

**Using PartiQL**

PartiQL does support to batch `Insert` `Update` `Delete` statements. It fits well for `Use case #1`, but it didn't fit `Use case #2` well. e.g., if I only use `Insert`, when there is already record existed, `Insert` will complain duplication error. If I only use `Update`, if there is no record existed, `Update` will complain conditional request error. If I batch `Insert` and `Update` together, `PartiQL` will complain that two statements could not point to the same record. And I don't think `PartiQL` will support something like store procedure, query before insert or update.

**Summary**

Anyway, if there is no better way, I will have to use `batchWrite` and put all columns into Update request. It is not ideal but it is workable, unlike `PartiQL` approach which has no walk-around for `Use case #2`.

Answer (score 0):

UpdateItem supports upsert if the item doesn't exist.
In my case i had to increment a number attribute every time i write a new record.
I am using a single table design. So using BatchWrite you can have 2 writes:

1. Create new item
2. Update with an ADD action - not SET

Below is C# code snippet:

```
var trx2 = new TransactWriteItem()
{
    Update = new Update
    {
        Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
        {
            { "PK" , new AttributeValue { S = model.PK }},
            { "SK" , new AttributeValue { S = model.SK }},
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"#V", "Value"}
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
        {
            {":incr", new AttributeValue {N = "1"}},
        },
        UpdateExpression = "ADD #V :incr",
        TableName = this.tableName,
    }
}
```

I hope this helps :)